# How to return just the text from a HTML snippet?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a HTML snippet that looks like this:

```
<pre>zdfsfsf<br/>adfadfadf
adfadfasdfadfad  adfadf adf 
Mill Valley, CA 94941
122-2323-24124
Email: adfadfadf<br/><i>sfsfsfsf</i></pre>
<br/>
```

I want to strip all tags and just have the text.

Content should look like this:

```
zdfsfsf adfadfadf
adfadfasdfadfad  adfadf adf 
Mill Valley, CA 94941
122-2323-24124
Email: adfadfadf sfsfsfsf
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
cells = row.find_all('td')
for c in cells:
    c.STRIP_HTML_TAGS()?????? <--WHAT IS THIS FUNCTION?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`get_text()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("""<pre>zdfsfsf<br/>adfadfadf
... adfadfasdfadfad  adfadf adf 
... Mill Valley, CA 94941
... 122-2323-24124
... Email: adfadfadf<br/><i>sfsfsfsf</i></pre>
... <br/>""")
>>> print(soup.get_text())
zdfsfsfadfadfadf
adfadfasdfadfad  adfadf adf 
Mill Valley, CA 94941
122-2323-24124
Email: adfadfadfsfsfsfsf
>>>
```